# In client-side JavaScript, is it possible to capture an event and fire it at a later stage?

Tags: javascript, dom, event-handling, dom-events

I'm interested in doing something like this:

```
...
event.preventDefault();
...
el.dispatchEvent(event);
```

I tried this in Firefox, which threw an `NS_ERROR_ILLEGAL_VALUE` exception.

Is it possible to capture an event and fire it at a later stage?

---

For those that are interested, here's my high-level objective. I'm trying to determine when an underscore is typed into a textarea (i.e. <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>-</kbd>). Unfortunately, Firefox reports the `keyCode` and `charCode` for this event are 0, the same value given to the tilde (<kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>`</kbd>) keystroke. To disambiguate, my idea is to capture the event, suppress its default behaviour, and "release" it on *another* textarea. I'd then inspect the value of this (hidden) textarea to determine which key was pressed.

**Update:** I'm using `onkeydown`, not `onkeypress`.

Comment: Take a look at [https://developer.mozilla.org/event...](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.dispatchEvent) if you haven't already. :)

Comment: (1) Can't you just read the text content when you capture the event? and (2) wouldn't `event.preventDefault();` actually prevent the `el.dispatchEvent(event);` to perform any action you want?

Comment: That's funny- String.fromCharCode(95) returns an underscore, and 126 is the tilde. Where are you getting the zeroes?

Comment: aha! Apparently Firefox is helpful when it comes to "keypress" but not "keydown" (I'm using "keydown").

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, an event already in the queue cannot be "reused" because it cannot be "pulled out" of the queue. It's given to you, then to the next handler in line, and so on, but the native delegate is the same for all of them. So, you have to make a new one. Since you're saying you can't get all the data about the event out, that's a problem.

An easier trick may be to watch the textarea for change, and then delete the underscore when it appears in the text. If you want to maintain the cursor position, you can look [here](http://www.webmasterworld.com/forum91/4527.htm) for a solution on how to exactly position the cursor (RonPK's response).

Out of curiosity, according to my test [here](http://jsbin.com/ajeta3/5), Firefox 4 reports the correct charCode and shift state. Is this a specific version/OS issue?

Comment: Useful answer. Thanks for including an example. I, too, see the correct `charCode` in Firefox. I updated the example to use ["keydown" rather than "keypress"](http://jsbin.com/ajeta3/6), however, and I see 0 for both. >.<

Comment: Interesting! I see keyCode 109 for both keydown and keyup in ff4. Key down/up don't have a charCode since that's synthesized after all the relevant keys are released, but they should have a keyCode. More details here: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/keys.html

Answer (score -1):

What's wrong with:

```
String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode);
```

?

E.g. within the event handler:

```
var character = String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode);
if (character === '_') {
    // Do something.
}
```

Comment: The problem is that `event.keyCode` is 0 in both cases.

Comment: I didn't realize that this is relevant at the time I posted the question, but I'm using `onkeydown` rather than `onkeypress`.

Comment: I don't think I had a good reason for using `onkeydown` rather than `onkeypress` (I didn't realize at the time that one might be more reliable than the other). I just tried using `onkeypress` instead and everything appears to work just as it did. :)

Comment: @davidchambers, be great if you could accept my answer :) at the moment I've still got a downvote, which kinda sucks.

Comment: Despite the fact that I found your answer helpful, I can't accept it since it doesn't answer the question "is it possible to capture an event and fire it at a later stage?". I'd like to retract my downvote, but Stack Overflow prevents me from doing so until your answer has been edited.